# Align Text in Bootstrap Tables within the same Data Cell

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

Iam using Bootstrap3 and Django. In a Table I want to align some Data with and its units.

Let me Draw you a picture:

```
+-----+-------------+

|Text | Data + Unit |

+-----+-------------+

| Foo | 1000 Bars   |

+-----+-------------+ 
|Foo2 | 500 Fobars  |
+-----+-------------+
```

The places in the Data have to align but the units have diffrent char length.
I ended up with

```
<td class="text-right"><dd>{{f.data}}</dd> {{f.units}}
```

Which gives me a linebreake within cell. I also tried to put a little extra table within the cell, but this didn't worked out.

I need something like a tabulator - but I lake the knowledge of html and css to ask the right question.

How would your solutions for this problem look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to fix this.. The simplest would be to set the dd's as to display as a inline-blocks.

You would give the table, td or the dd itself a class and apply display: inline-block to it and give it a set width (wide enough for the longest units). See below.

```
<table class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Data + Unit</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td><dd>1000</dd>Bars</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo2</td>
        <td>
            <dd>500</dd>FoBars
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the css

```
.data dd {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly but if you want all the dd's to be the same width you could change it to an inline-block and set them to a fixed width or put the units into a separate column.

Comment: Basicly I wand 500,00 Dollar and 4000,00 Pound having their decimalplaces aligned even tough the names Dollar and Pound are of diffrent length. In a Textdocument I would use a tabulator for this. I can't use a seperate colum because the Layout of the Table has to be in this way - at least optical.

Comment: This will work but you need to make sure that the width is set to the widest you need as if there are any units that are to long it will push it out of align again.

  .data dd {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 6px;
   width: 60px;
   text-align: right;
  }

Comment: The last part did it, thanks - if you would edit your answer that it reflect this changes, that would be great! Thanks!